# How should I generate unique group IDs for groups of objects based on bespoke fields in a distributed server?

Tags: java, grouping, distributed-computing, ignite

We have an app server, which processes a large volume of incoming objects.

One of its functions, is to group those objects into groups, based on bespoke collection of grouping keys that depend on object type.

E.g, there is a grouping rule table that says:

- Object type 1: grouping keys are col1, col2, col4, col5
- Object type 2: grouping keys are col2, col3 ...

Originally, we had a singleton server, and the problem was solved by having an in-memory index, mapping an object type + grouping key string, to a group ID. Then, we had a synchronized code that would check if the index contained an entry for grouping keys of a given object. If so, the object got the group ID from the cache, otherwise, we assigned group ID of the object to be its object ID - and stored it in the cache.

This worked well... until the server was re-designed from a singleton, to several distributed server instances using Ignite cache to store the data (including the grouping cache).

Due to inherent slowness of the Ignite solution, a race condition was introduced, since the synchronization mechanism used in a singleton to prevent them could not sustain the slowness of Ignite (transactions are too slow).

What can be done to solve this problem in a distributed situation, avoiding either race conditions (which produce different group IDs for objects that should be in same group), OR even worse, false positive grouping (e.g. grouping 2 objects that should be in different groups)?

**Constraints:**

- Pure hashing function cannot be used, due to a risk of hash key collisions. The grouping may not have false positives, ever (e.g. assigning same group ID to objects that should not be groupd together). Imagine that this could lead to loss of PII, or other high risk - so no matter how good the hashing function is and how rare collisions are, they are still unacceptable.
- Solution must be realtime, since grouping data is used in other functionalities of the server within seconds or possibly fractions of a second of processing an object. So if there is some post-processing sweep to re-group things "correctly" is introduced with a latency of 30 seconds, that risks 30 seconds of group level updates being done to incorrect group membership.
- Maintaining individual lists of group IDs synchronized between server instances via messaging system is not acceptable due to high volume of data (e.g. 5 servers * 1million objects would mean sending 4 million group ID updates). That was the whole point of having an Ignite cache.
- Technical constraints: Java server instances, running on distinct Linux servers. They use a homegrown MQ like messaging system to talk to each other in general, and Ignite cache cluster to store shared data instead of local in-memory cache (which is the source of the problem).

Answer (score 2):

The performance of Ignite can't cause a race condition. It doesn't matter whether an update takes a microsecond or a minute, a race condition is a synchronisation issue.

In any case, reading and writing a bunch of records in one unit says "transaction." Ignite supports distributed transactions.

```
try (Transaction tx = ignite.transactions().txStart()) {
    cache1.get(...);
    cache2.put();
    cache2.put();
    tx.commit();
}
catch (...) {
```

If you can't use transactions you need to either "manually" have locks (which is probably going to be slower) or have your Group ID be predictable. For example, your key for group one could be a concatenation of columns 1, 2, 4 and 5.

But really this is a data modelling question that may not be a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The performance of ignite does NOT cause race conditions - it causes it to be too slow to use in transaction context. Which means you get race condition because of lack of transactions.